Query data with space
I need get CITY names from station table where names city not start or end by character (a,e,i,o,u).
So I tried to do this:
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[^AEIOU][^aeiou]$')
ORDER BY city;

Some of my data has more than one word, example: Yazoo City, Marine On Saint Croix, so my query is not correct.
What should I do?

Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

Use https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expression; read the 'EXPLANATION' box carefully to understand what it is doing (and why it wouldn't match anything longer than two characters).

@tinazmu, note that different dbms's may have other regexp support.

Are you looking for ^[^AEIOU].*[^aeiou]$ regular expression? Note .* for arbitrary characters in the middle of the name

Is Yazoo City considered to end with o or y?

I prefer this version, which uses a regex alternation:
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^[aeiou]|[aeiou]$')
ORDER BY city;

This version is flexible, because it allows for the (unlikely) possibility that a city might be just one character.

A bit off-topic, but in Sweden there are several one letter villages, named Å or Ö.

@jarlh Ja, es ist sehr gut nein?

Just confirming one letter names do exist! (However vowels.)

WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(city, '^[^AEIOU].*[^aeiou]$')

'.' - Matches any character except NULL. (but including spaces) 
'*' - Matches zero or more occurrences.
please also take into account case sensitivity of city names ([^AEIOUaeiou])
database flavour not provided so used Oracle 
source: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php
